# Software to easily transfer windows between mobile/desktop/laptop

Tags: windows, gratis, android, window-manager

I've seen the file transfer question before, but never one regarding windows. I would like to, without my internet-connected devices being physically connected in any way, be able to send specific program windows to the other devices.

For instance, when I need to head out, I could right click on my web browser's title bar and select <kbd>Send To → Phone</kbd> or <kbd>Send To → Laptop</kbd>, and everything I had open in the browser would now be open on the target device (assuming I had that same browser installed on the target device) and close on the source device.

Getting complicated, I might be editing an image and want to send that editor and my progress over to another computer.

My desktop/laptops are all Windows, and my phone is an Android. Are there any free pieces of software that do this?

Comment: IIRC if you use Google Chrome amd have set up a Google account on all of your devices, you can link those devices together so that they share the same browser tabs, history, and account logins.

Comment: That's great for specific programs, but not for ones that don't have that specific functionality built in

Comment: If you switched to windows mobile instead of android this is a key feature of Windows 10.  "Continuum Windows 10" Google search that.

Comment: You question title is misleading. You do not want to transfer 'windows', you want to transfer program settings *and* state for all kinds of programs. That is not possible with one piece of software. I suggest you [edit] your question and limit yourself to **one program** that you want this functionality for.

Comment: If you can accept a terribly slow solution, then all that I can think of is to do everything on your home PC, but to remote into it. E.g. if you are not at home, you can use the Android version of TeamViewer to access your home PC remotely on your Android. A bad idea, but I know of no general purpose alternative :-(

Answer (score 1):

[Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) gives you the possibility to share/send Files, Links or Images from any Browser as Add-on or as installation from your Computer to your Mobile Device.
[image]
Also you can send Pictures/Links/Files from your Android to your Computer or Browser and vice versa.
[image]
[image]
With this you can Mirror all your incoming Messages from your Mobile Device on your Computer too. Or you can answer SMS or What's App Messages directly on your Computer- when you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out AirDroid: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en

I think it will fill *most* of your needs.

AirDroid synchronizes as much of your Android with your Windows desktop as possible. You can see your phone notifications on your desktop... in fact, you can even display your Android screen on your Windows desktop directly.

Another option I can think of would be Andromium: https://getsuperbook.com/

Andromium basically allows you to use your Android phone as your desktop operating system. Therefore you wouldn't need to "send" anything from one device to the other because you'd always be using the same device. It's currently in beta, but is very close to launching. I've used it with a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse and a wireless monitor and it works flawlessly.

I don't think there's any way to do *exactly* what you described because sending an image editor or similar application would require that the app itself exists on both platforms. There are image editors that span Android and Windows, but that method would be an app by app decision whereas AirDroid and Andromium are the two services that I have used that handle things on the OS level.

Comment: Thanks for sharing – but how does it fit? Airdroid is to remote-control your Android device and to transfer files. How does it fit the part to transfer all open browser-tabs, or an image editor state? Please see [our answer guide](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185), then [edit] your post to include the missing details. Or hit the "delete" link between your post and this comment if your recommendation doesn't match. Thanks a lot!